# Enabling c++11 on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I got the community version of Visual Studio 2013 and I thought that c++11 was supposed to be enabled by default.

However, the macro `__cplusplus` has a value of 199711L (c++98) rather than 201103L (c++11). Furthermore, if I try to run c++11 specific code (like`constexpr int a = 5;`) it gives an error in the compiler. How do I enable c++11?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That the value of `__cplusplus` is still `199711L` is a bug, which has been [reported to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763051/a-value-of-predefined-macro-cplusplus-is-still-199711l).

That shouldn't stop you from writing and compiling C++11 code. It should just work (nothing special to configure).

**Beware** that Visual Studio 2013's C++11 implementation is [not complete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). Among the unsupported features is `constexpr`, which explains why you're getting a compile error ;-)

Comment: As of June 20, 2016, the [bug reported to Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763051/a-value-of-predefined-macro-cplusplus-is-still-199711l) has been closed and deferred. `__cplusplus` is still 199711L at this time. Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.